# How to upload images with reduced size and their thumbnails?

Tags: php, image, upload, gallery, thumbnails

I have this script for multi-upload of images in the gallery:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];                          

echo $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'img/galerie/'.$datum.'-'.$nazevAlba.'-'.$k_dj.'/';  
echo $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 

if( move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)){   
    $nazevSouboru = 'img/galerie/'.$datum.'-'.$nazevAlba.'-'.$k_dj.'/'.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO `galerie_fotky` (`k_album`,`odkaz`)
        VALUES ('".$_GET['idAlba']."','".$nazevSouboru."')
    "); 
    echo true;
}else{
    echo false;
}
```

}

What I would need to do, is to upload these images with some reduced size so it would not take so much space on server. How can I accomplish this? And second issue is: for each image to save in the same folder its thumbnails, let´s say with height 150px.

Comment: You looking for soe class that creates thumbnails of the images?

Comment: I hoped it can be done only by expanding my script... But if it can be done everything on this one page with my script, I could use some class... :)

Comment: May be this could help a bit http://davidwalsh.name/create-image-thumbnail-php

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising... And do you know how to upload the big images with some compression?

Comment: Well i always use some thumbnail class to create thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like any of those below:

http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/ (really good one)
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

But the truth is that GD has some very simple functionality for image resizing as well. 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php